# targeting center of mass - scipy / numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, linear-algebra

Given the following:

```
from scipy.ndimage import center_of_mass
from numpy import array

A = array([
  [ 255, 255, 0, 0 ]
  [ 255, 255, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0   , 0,  0, 0 ],
  [ 0   , 0,  0, 0 ]
])

cm = center_of_mass(A)
# cm = (0.5, 0.5)

centered = ???
cmc = center_of_mass(centered)
# cmc ~= (1.5,1.5)
```

How do we **shift** this ndarray / image so that it is centered, based on it's center of mass?

Our target outcome here would be the following:

```
centered = array([
  [ 0,   0,   0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 255, 255, 0 ],
  [ 0, 255, 255, 0 ],
  [ 0,   0,   0, 0 ]
])
```

Comment: Look for the point that has smallest euclidean dist from `cm` and slice centered on it?

Comment: This will have infinite number of solutions without constraints.

Comment: OK, let me add some clarity around constraints to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's easy:

1. find the geometrical center

   ```
   import numpy as np

   c1 = center_of_mass(np.ones_like(A))
   #or : c1 = [A.shape[0]/2.,A.shape[1]/2.]
   ```
2. shift the matrix by the diffrenence

   ```
   S = np.roll(A, c1[0]-cm[0] , axis=0)
   S = np.roll(S, c1[0]-cm[0] , axis=1)
   ```

**The answer will be:**

```
    Out[18]: 
    array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
           [  0, 255, 255,   0],
           [  0, 255, 255,   0],
           [  0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

Comment: Since `roll` will only work for integers, is there a way to do this when the center of mass is located at sub-pixel values?

Comment: @curious_cosmo. Are you familiar with image resampling?

Comment: I had to add an `int` function to get the answer. `S = np.roll(A, int(c1[0] - cm[0]), axis=0)` After that I got the desired matrix. Apparently the array needs integer format or an `__index__` method for the slice indices. I understand some clarity is lost here without a proper method--i.e. getting an exact solution--so any further help with how to do that, have at it.